# Using Gstreamer 1.0 with Qt Multimedia

Tags: qt, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

According to the [latest docs for Qt 5.5](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.5), Gstreamer 1.0 is supported via Qt Multimedia. However, I can't seem to find much more information about it (the guy from [this post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/62692-Qt-5-5-GStreamer-integration) seems to be in the same boat). I need 1.0 support in Windows so I am currently using QtGstreamer.

Previously in Phonon, Qt had gstreamer 0.10 support (at least on Linux). Does this 1.0 support extend to more platforms, like Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GStreamer is only used by Qt Multimedia on Unix platforms. See [this page](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.5.0_Multimedia_Backends) for more information.

On that same page, you'll see the Windows support is limited to DirectShow or Media Foundation.